# What information can be taken by submitting an online form?

Tags: encryption, vpn, openvpn

Sorry I'm pretty clueless with this stuff..

I know that vpn hides your IP address when just browsing websites, but how about submitting an online form, such as when you send an inquiry?

Would my IP address (fake if using VPN?) and device-specific address like Mac address etc. go through? What else? Meaning my anonymity would be compromised...?

Answer (score 2):

If you connect and submit a form using your VPN connection, the site will get your VPN address, not your main IP address.

But with a little javascript file they can get a lot of information about you:

- Browser type, version and revision
- All plugins installed
- You operational system
- Screen size and depth

If they succesfully exploit [DNS Leak](https://www.dnsleaktest.com/what-is-a-dns-leak.html), or put Flash or Java on the page, they can even get your real IP.

Anonimity is a illusion. The only thing you can do is being harder to identify, but you cannot never ever be impossible to identify, no matter how much you try. If anyone **really** wants to identify you, the only possible defense is get disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

Submitting a form is no different from browsing a site.  It is, in fact, submitted by the exact same or very similar kind of request to the one used to get the website in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Although this part is probably obvious, I did not see this stated in any of the other answers.  All the information you enter into the form can be potentially obtained (depending on how the form is coded) at the very least by the person who receives the form.  This is why it is good to use different passwords for different sites (e.g. the owner of one site won't be able to log in as you on other sites you log in to).  The form information may also be intercepted by a hacker, or may be sent to several people.  Encryption helps prevent unintended recipients from being able to get the data.